# Asymptotic estimate of a double Laplace-Fourier integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, fourier-transform

While reading a physics paper I bumped into the following integral:

$\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\, e^{- x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,e^{iy}\,\text{cos}(\frac{\sqrt{x+ ay}}{a} + \frac{\sqrt{x- ay}}{a}) $,

where "a" is a parameter.

The authors claim that in the limit $a \to 0$ the integral vanishes because of the highly oscillating nature of the integrand function involved in the Fourier Transform. This closely reminds me of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, however I can not understand how I should apply this lemma in the present case, especially because of the functional form of the argument of the cosine.

Is it the correct approach to invoke the Rieman-Lebesgue lemma or should I follow another path to prove their claim?

Comment: The change of variables $x= a^2 u, y= av$  puts the dependence on $a$ outside the cosine expression, but how are we to make sense of the $\cos (\sqrt{ x-y})$ when $y>>x$? Did the paper address this issue?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz no, the cosine is just multiplying the exponential

Comment: @MathWonk That is a good point, actually nothing is said regarding this issue.

Comment: @MathWonk maybe they are using a sloppy notation and what they really mean is that we have to fix x to some value and then perform the fourier integral on the admissible domain. After that we perform the x integral

Comment: @MathWonk Note that $\cos(\sqrt z) $ is an entire function.

Comment: @Gary Good point I had not considered! But what about the problem that cosine does not distribute across a sum of square roots?